# Is it possible to implement two-way SSL in AWS Certificate Manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, aws-certificate-manager

Right now I have a server which should only be accessible by clients who have a particular valid certificate installed in their browser. This is called two-way SSL and it's a way to authenticate clients. I was wondering if it is possible to implement this in AWS Certificate Manager?

I'm asking this because when I do this manually, I have to generate client certificates on my machine individually using the CA's certificate and key. But when I use AWS Certificate Manager I don't think the key is accessible for me to generate the client certificates. Is that right? Does that mean that I can not use AWS Certificate Manager if I want to implement two-way SSL?

Comment: I have tried and failed to find a solution for this; ended up terminating SSL on EC2 instance.

Comment: Well, the worst case scenario is that I'll implement the two-way SSL by generating self-signed certificates and introduce them in the server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot use AWS ACM issued certificates as client certificates since it only allows to associate with following AWS services.

- AWS API Gateway
- AWS CloudFront
- AWS ELB/ALB